# The problem in adding a role when the user has the invitations

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this script for invitations, how can I when the number of invitations is reached the one who made the invitations receives the role?

```
member.guild.fetchInvites().then(guildInvites => {
    const inv = invites[member.guild.id];
    invites[member.guild.id] = guildInvites;
    const invite = guildInvites.find(i => !inv.get(i.code) || inv.get(i.code).uses < i.uses);
    const inviter = bot.users.get(invite.inviter.id);
    const logChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === "");
    logChannel.send("<@" + member.user.id + "> " + "** joined**" + " invited by " + inviter.tag + `(${invite.uses} invites)`);
    var role= member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Test");
    if(invite.uses == 25) {
        member.inviter.addRole(role);
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: I want when the user has made that number of invitations, to receive that role, not the incoming member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `invite.inviter` (the user who created the invite) instead of `member` (the member who joined the server).

```js
member.guild.fetchInvites().then(async guildInvites => {
    const inv = invites[member.guild.id];
    invites[member.guild.id] = guildInvites;
    const invite = guildInvites.find(i => !inv.get(i.code) || inv.get(i.code).uses < i.uses);
    const inviter = bot.users.get(invite.inviter.id);
    const logChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === "");
    logChannel.send("<@" + member.user.id + "> " + "** joined**" + " invited by " + inviter.tag + `(${invite.uses} invites)`);
    if(invite.uses == 25) {
        const role = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Test");
        const inviterMember = await member.guild.fetchMember(invite.inviter.id);
        inviterMember.addRole(role);
    }
});
```

Comment: member.guild.members.fetch is not a function

Comment: Discord js v11.6

Comment: Oh I see. Fixed.